# How to fix "error: (401) Unauthorized" when trying to get OAuth grants from backpack.tf?

Tags: vb.net, oauth

I'm trying to get OAuth grants from https://backpack.tf/ As explained in the developer page : https://backpack.tf/developer/pages/oauth_grants

Here is my code :

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text 

Public Class Form1   
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim client_id As String = "myclientid"
    Dim client_secret As String = "myclientsecret"


    Dim resp As String = WebRequestPOST("https://backpack.tf/oauth/access_token", client_id, client_secret)

    RichtextBox1.Text = resp
End Sub


Public Function WebRequestPOST(ByVal url As String, ByVal client_id As String, ByVal client_secret As String) As String
    Dim wrequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
    wrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    wrequest.Accept = "1.0"       
    wrequest.Method = "POST"        


    Dim postData As String = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" & client_id & "&client_secret=" & client_secret & "scope=read write"

    Dim postDataByte As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    Using Writer As New IO.BinaryWriter(wrequest.GetRequestStream)
        Writer.Write(postDataByte)
    End Using

    Dim wresponse As String = ""
    Try
        wresponse = New StreamReader(wrequest.GetResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd
    Catch ex As Exception
        wresponse = ex.ToString
        Return wresponse
    End Try

    Return wresponse
End Function
End Class
```

It's always returning "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()"

I tried many diferents methods like adding :

```
 wrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "myUserToken")
```

or:

```
wrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer myUserToken")
```

(Like reddit OAuth) But still same result

I can't find more informations about it on https://backpack.tf/developer/ or even by reading code of all existing bot in github.

Using DotNetOpenAuth Library don't help me either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you've got the right/correct values for client id, client secret, scope, and grant type (if any of those are wrong, you could get a 401 response, depends on the server code though and I'm not familiar with this one), you do have an error in constructing the postdata body.

You are missing the '&' delimiter for the scope parameter, this will make the client secret include the scope, which will certainly make the client secret wrong.

```
. . . "&client_secret=" & client_secret & "&scope=read write"
                                           ^
```

Comment: I feel so bad for forgeting a "&"! thank you so much!!! it work now!!!!

Comment: You are welcome.  Please consider accepting the answer when it provides you a solution.

Comment: not used to the site yet. It's done now. Thanks again